# struts2 dynamically change style on textfield

Tags: struts2, textfield

I'm trying to dynamically change the style of a `Struts2` textfield to change background color depending on a certain conditions.

- Question 1 - is this possible
- Question 2 - from other posts here - I've tried the following but the style is not getting evaluated?

Any pointers on how this can be done or what I have incorrect below?

```
<s:if test='%{contactStatusCode == "ARE" }'>
<s:set var="AREStyle" value="%{'background:#eeeeee'}"/>

<s:textfield name      = "followUpComment"
             id        = "followUpComment[%{#index.index}]"
             style     = "%{#AREStyle}"
             size      = "15"
             maxlength = "100"  />
```

Comment: struts2 attribute for style is `cssStyle` not `style`. Although I think this is a bad way of applying styles, I would prefer using a css class or change the background using javascript/jquery

Comment: Thanks Anu - using cssStyle instead of style got it working..cheers for that.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing css class of textfield

```
 <s:textfield name="followUpComment" cssClass="%{contactStatusCode == 'ARE' ? 'areClass' : 'notAreClass'}" />
```